# Button to share website link on facebook Timeline

Tags: facebook

How can I have a button on my webpage that shares the link the user is viewing automatically to his or her facebook timeline? 
For eg if he or she is in mypage.com/aboutme then the link will be shared on his or her facebook timeline when clicked...

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible without user prior Facebook authentication.
If you get theat beforehands, then

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div>
```

Also, make sure you control the og:meta properties in the HTML head

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mysite.me/my.png" />
<meta property="og:description" content="mycontent..." />
<meta property="og:title" content="blueflower"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="mysite.me"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mysite.me"/>
```

Best

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it. 
This can be done using http://www.addthis.com/ generated code.